# Hacer un método estático Conexion() que conecta a una base de datos, ¿buen diseño o no?

Tags: c#

Tengo la siguiente clase con el método `Conectar()`, que lo que hace es abrir una conexión a una base de datos Firebird. Lo hace todo correctamente, y luego a este método lo llamo desde otra clase que hereda de esta, haciendo un `ConexionFB.Conexion().Open()` para abrir la conexión, etc.

Mi duda es si he hecho bien poniéndolo como `static` o no, ya que esto no me queda muy claro. El método lo utilizo para un login de una página web.

```
public class ConexionFB
{
    private static FbConnectionStringBuilder parametros_conexion = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
    private static FbConnection conexion = new FbConnection();

    protected static FbConnection Conectar()
    {
        parametros_conexion.DataSource = "localhost";
        parametros_conexion.Port = 3050;
        parametros_conexion.Database = @"C:\FirebirdDB\USUARIOS.FDB";
        parametros_conexion.UserID = "SYSDBA";
        parametros_conexion.Password = "masterkey";
        parametros_conexion.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;

        conexion = new FbConnection(parametros_conexion.ToString());

        return conexion;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tener el método `Conectar` como `static`, no es necesariamente malo, aunque no entiendo por qué lo tienes como `protected`, eso no me parece correcto.

Lo que *definitivamente no está bien* es que estés guardando el resultado en una variable estática global `conexion`. Normalmente, este patrón se usa con la intención de compartir una conexión global para el app entero (aunque en tu caso, estás reasignando la variable a cada llamada, lo que es raro en sí). Compartir una conexión global ***nunca*** es buena idea, particularmente en apps multi usuarios (multi hilos), como debes ser tu caso, ya que se trata de una página web.

La razón por la que no es aconsejable es que, si más de un usuario trata de efectuar una acción al mismo tiempo y tratan de usar la misma conexión, varias cosas peligrosas pueden suceder. He aquí algunos ejemplos:

- Dependiendo de la base de datos, puede lanzarte excepciones por tratar de manejar varias result sets al mismo tiempo.
- Puedes corromper tus datos si las transacciones de los 2 usuarios se mezclan juntos.

Mas bien, permite que cada usuario (hilo) abra y cierre la conexión según la necesidad, idealmente usando un *connection pool* para minimizar el costo de "abrir" una conexión, aunque lo típico es que esto se haga automáticamente según el *connection string* que uses (no sé cómo funciona con Firebird).

En tu lugar, yo restructuraría la clase de esta forma (nota que el *connection string* sí queda cómo estático, eso no es un problema. Pero la variable `conexion` en sí queda eliminida de la clase):

```
public static class ConexionFB
{
    private static readonly string ConnectionString;

    static ConexionFB()
    {
        var parametros_conexion = new FbConnectionStringBuilder();
        parametros_conexion.DataSource = "localhost";
        parametros_conexion.Port = 3050;
        parametros_conexion.Database = @"C:\FirebirdDB\USUARIOS.FDB";
        parametros_conexion.UserID = "SYSDBA";
        parametros_conexion.Password = "masterkey";
        parametros_conexion.ServerType = FbServerType.Default;
        ConnectionString = parametros_conexion.ToString();
    }

    public static FbConnection Conectar()
    {
        return new FbConnection(ConnectionString);
    }
}
```

Ejemplo de cómo usarlo:

```
using(var connexion = ConexionFB.Conectar())
{
    // ... usar conexión aquí...
}
```

---

Pequeña nota adicional: aunque no conozco Firebird, sospecho que no sea buena idea de usar `sysdba` para la conexión. Suena cómo que estás usando un usuario administrador con demasiados permisos.

Comment: Vale, muchas gracias. Lo de poner el método protected lo he hecho porque mi intención era  usar el método Conectar(), solo en la clase que heredaba de esta.

Comment: Y otra cosa que diferencia hay de usar:  `using(var connexion = ConexionFB.Conectar())` a no poner el using y crear la variable sin el using? Perdona pero soy bastante nuevo en esto

Comment: Te refiero a [using (Instrucción, Referencia de C#)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/yh598w02.aspx) para leer al respecto. En pocas palabras, tiene que ver con clases que implementan la interfaz [`IDisposable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.idisposable.aspx), que asumo es el caso con la clase `FbConnection`. En esos casos, el `using` te garantiza que el objeto en cuestión va a liberar sus recursos al final del bloque (ejecutando el método `Dispose()`), aún cuando suceda una excepción. Sin el `using`, escribir el código equivalente a mano es bien largo.

Comment: Lo que hace el Using es ahorrarte tenes que escribir el Try{} y Finally{"Dispose de la variable conexion"}

Comment: @sstan En el caso que la aplicación fuese de escritorio podría usar la variable de conexión como static no?

Comment: @Alejandro: Depende de la aplicación. Aun una aplicación de escritorio con un solo usuario pudiera efectuar trabajo en varios hilos. En ese caso, usar una sola conexión es peligroso.

Answer (score 0):

Para ese caso yo uso los métodos **no estáticos** (de instancias). Pues cada usuario es una conexión independiente y podrían ocurrir colisiones de sessiones de usuarios.

Comment: Un método estático no resulta necesariamente en conexiones compartidas.

Answer (score 0):

Yo en el 90% de las veces uso un Lazy Singleton para las conexiones a base de datos, al ser lazy tenemos "thread safe" y la propagación de excepciones es correcta. Por otro lado el patrón Singleton lo que hace es que si no hay ninguna instancia creada de la conexión, se crea, y en caso de que otro cliente la haya inicializado anteriormente, no es necesario volver a hacerlo, por lo que tendremos N clientes, manejando una única conexión. Habría que tener cuidado eso si, en cada operación que tengamos con BD de hacer connection.open y connection.close para mas seguridad.

public class SingletonDB
{

```
private static readonly Lazy<ExampleClass> _instance = new Lazy<ExampleClass>();

public static ExampleClass Instance { get { return _instance.Value; } }

private readonly SqlConnection _connection = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["DB_NAME"].ConnectionString);


public DataTable GetAll()
{

    DataTable auxDt = new DataTable();
    SqlDataAdapter auxDa = new SqlDataAdapter();
    SqlCommand auxCmd = new SqlCommand("SP_NAME", _connection);
    auxCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
    auxCmd.Parameters("PARAMETER_NAME", parameterValue, SqlDbType.BigInt);


    try
    {
        if (_connection.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
        {
            _connection.Open();
        }

        auxDa.SelectCommand = auxCmd;
        auxDa.Fill(auxDt);
        _connection.Close();
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        throw;
    }

    return auxDt;
}
```

Comment: Pero, ¿qué sucede cuando 2 clientes necesitan la conexión al mismo tiempo?

Comment: No ocurriría nada, de hecho es una única instancia de la conexión a la que se conectan N clientes, por lo que la clase de acceso a datos sería tambíen un singleton deberías comprobar el estado de la conexión en la misma clase en la que accedes, dejo un ejemplo de código en otra respuesta aparte.

Comment: Este diseño te va a dar errores en una ambiente multi-hilos. Si 2 clientes tratan de usar la misma conexión al mismo tiempo puedes recibir errores porque tienes mas de un "resultset" abierto al mismo tiempo. O peor, si se trata de 2 clientes efectuando cambios en 2 transacciones distintas, puedes recibir errores o introducir cambios en la transacción equivocada tal vez causando corrupción de datos. El uso de un singleton no es apropiado para conexiones de bases de datos. Cada cliente debe poder trabajar en una conexión independiente e aíslada de los demás clientes.

Comment: Creo que el Lazy si no me equivoco, hace los locks, por lo que es seguro en entorno multihilos, según la documentación de Microsoft.

Comment: El uso de `Lazy` solo te garantiza que todos los hilos van a obtener la misma conexión sin problemas. Pero no provee ninguna garantía sobre el uso de dicha conexión una vez que la obtienes.  La clase [SqlConnection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlconnection(v=vs.110).aspx) no ha sido diseñada para ser compartida por varios hilos, por lo que no es apropiado de usarlo en un singleton. Si sigues el enlace, verás que abajo dice lo siguiente en cuanto a la clase `SqlConnection`: *No se garantiza que los miembros de instancia sean seguros para subprocesos.*

Comment: La solución podría ser crear tantas conexiones nuevas como clientes se conecten?, aunque la instancia sea la misma y sigamos usando el singleton?.

Comment: Le sigo dando vueltas, si controlas la concurrencia y las transacciones directamente en las consultas (commit, rollback, etc) no debería haber problemas de corrupción de datos.